# Adding a Checkbox to Office Word C# Interop

Tags: c#, office-interop

*Note: I'm using Office Word 2007*

I need to replace specific parts of a Word Document with comboboxes, checkboxes, text, etc..
I find "tags" using Regular Expression, and then iterate over regex Matches to get the specific text to replace.

```
var range = doc.Content; // where doc is current active word document
var matches = GetRegexMatches();
foreach (var match in matches){        
    if(range.Find.Execute(match.Value)){ // match.Value equals to the "tag" im searching
        range.Collapse();
        Word.ContentControl checkbox = range.ContentControls.Add(Word.WdContentControlType.wdContentControlCheckbox);
        checkbox.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

This code adds some weird box (I guess a `ContentControl` object, but not of type checkbox). Debugging it didn't help because it just stops the debugger.

[image]

I tried following another similar stackoverflow thread, but using a `FormField`  instead of `ContentControl` just adds a grey checkbox which is disabled by default and unchangeable programatically.

Am I doing something wrong or it cannot be done in this Office version? Or both?

Comment: If you are OK with an ActiveX checkbox control, this should do the trick: `var cb = range.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl("Forms.CheckBox.1");
                                cb.OLEFormat.Object.Caption = "my Checkbox";`  Would that do?

Comment: Checkbox content controls weren't avaiable in Word 2007; they were introduced in Word 2010. Formfields will work, but you need to protect the document as a form. Legacy ActiveX controls (suggestion by LocEngineer) will trigger macro security (they have a programmable interface) and may have issues when printing. What is the purpose of the document you're creating? How will it be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, if you are working with Office 2010+ and the document you're trying to open has been created in a version previous to the 2010, it gets opened in `Compatibility Mode` which disables many of the new functionalities in order to not break the file. That includes Comboboxes, Checkboxes, etc.. There's no workaround to this, other than opening the document in new Office version and saving it as newer version.